# How can I get this graph into the form of an inversely proportional function?

Tags: graphs

I have written this piece of code to make a graph of the resistance of a NTC-resistor depending on the temperature. I know that it has an inversely proportional form, but I can't get it to make such a graph which doesn't go through each point but keeps the form of an inversely proportional function. How can I change this to have it have that form?

```
%\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
title={\textbf{Grafiek 1 aan de hand van \textit{Tabel 2}}},
xlabel = {$T$($^\circ$C)},
ylabel = {$R_{\mathrm{NTC}}$},
xmin = 20, xmax = 72,
ymin = 0, ymax = 50,
xtick = {0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
ytick = {0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
ymajorgrids = true,
grid style = dashed,
]


\addplot[ 
color = blue,
mark = *,
smooth, 
]
coordinates {
(22,49.9)(25,45.5)(28,41.1)(33,36.2)(36,31.6)(40,28.6)(45,23.7)(48,21.6)
(51,20.5)(55,18.1)(58,16.5)(63,14.9)(72,10.8)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={\textbf{Grafiek 1 aan de hand van \textit{Tabel 2}}},
xlabel = {$T$ (\si{\degreeCelsius})},
ylabel = {$R_{\mathrm{NTC}}$},
xmin = 20, xmax = 80,
ymin = 0, ymax = 50,
ymajorgrids = true,
grid style = dashed,
]

\addplot[blue, 
     domain=20:80,          %   <-- added 
     samples=7,             %   <-- added 
     mark = *, 
     smooth] 
     {1000/x};              %   <-- changed
 \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just a fraction quicker! :)

Comment: @Moriambar, I rarely have such a luck! :) :)

Comment: Lol and the solution was *exactly* the same too! well deserved +1 :P